# my app triggers: prevented an unrecognized app from starting

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote small calculator app in C# WPF and want to share with my friends. 
I sent the app and when they are opening it, Windows 10 launching message:

Defender prevented an unrecognized app from starting, unknown publisher.

How can I send this app without scary popups being triggered?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are going to need to build an install package for them to install the application.  this may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776(v=vs.110).aspx